# How to print checked checkbox values?

Tags: javascript, html

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
            <script src="scripts.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <button id = "button1" type="button" onclick="filterValues();">Submit</button>
        </body>
    </html>
```

My javascript:

```
var checkingValues = ["Cat", "Dog", "Horse", "Tree"];
var createCheckboxes;

var saveValues;
document.write("Choose from the options below:  </br> </br>");

for (var i = 0; i < checkingValues.length; i++) { 

    createCheckboxes = document.createElement("INPUT");
    var checkbox = createCheckboxes.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    createCheckboxes.setAttribute("value", checkingValues[i]);

    var checkBoxText = document.body.appendChild(createCheckboxes) + document.write(createCheckboxes.value +"</br>");
}

//try to save checked values
if(createCheckboxes.checked){
        saveValues = checkbox;
    }

function filterValues() {

    document.write(saveValues);
}
```

My idea is to generate a checkbox and print(filter) the selected items from the checkbox by saving the selected items in to a new array and just print them on a cick. I feel i need to make a simple if statement for that but i cant seem to write the values in the global saveValues variable. I know that is not the smartest way to do it but i want to know how to do it. I want to use pure JS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're restricted to pure Javascript, you could always do the following:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++){
  if(inputs[i].type == 'checkbox' && inputs[i].checked) {
    //print
    console.log(inputs[i].value);
  }
}
```

That will get all checked checkboxes on the page and print their values. Instead of printing to the console you could do some other logic, or add the checkbox to a second array for later use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

function filterValues() {

```
for (var i = 0; i < checkingValues.length; i++) { 

  if(createCheckboxes.checked){
        saveValues = checkbox;
    }
}

document.write(saveValues);
```

}